# How to initiate a ListView in android using a pre-defined array?

Tags: android, eclipse

I've passes by this tutorial:

[Android: Creating and populating ListView items in XML](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-creating-and-populating-listview-items-in-xml/)

I want to initialize a ListView in the xml not the code.

my array.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string-array name="anyArray">
        <item>one</item>
        <item>two</item>
        <item>three</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

my activity_main.xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:entries="@array/anyArray" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

When I switch to the layout, I get this warning

```
Couldn't resolve resource @array/anyArray
```

and no items are displayed. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your resources' names should only contain [a-z0-9._]. Rename your `Array` to all lower case characters.

Comment: Thanks, the warning disappeared. But the contents appear only on run-time. Is it possible to see them in the design?

Comment: They should appear in design in Eclipse (I don't know if it does on Netbeans or not). Try closing the layout and opening it again after saving the changes.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse, it didn't work. Still not appearing but only in the run-time.

Comment: try setting the height to a fixed value (200 dip for e.g.) for testing